'Maximum call stack size exceeded' when using tsibble::fill_gaps() in a shinylive webr app
I am using shinylive (v0.2.0) to write a Shiny (v1.8.1.1) app to run in the browser (Safari v17.5,  19618.2.12.11.6) using webr. The app takes data where each row represents an event and counts the number of events each day, then uses those counts to produce a time-series model. To make sure zero counts are included in the model, once I have used dplyr::count() to count the number of events and tsibble::as_tsibble() to create a tsibble, I use tsibble::fill_gaps() to create zero counts for any days with no events.
All this works fine when running the Shiny app in RStudio. When I try to run the same app in the browser using shinylive::export(), the browser produces the Javascript error Unhandled Promise Rejection: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded and references shinylive.js:33925. This only happens when tsibble::fill_gaps() is included in the code -- if I remove tsibble::fill_gaps() the code runs in webr as expected.
Here is a reprex showing the problem: this code runs when using Shiny in RStudio, but not when using webr in the browser (at least for me).
library(bslib)
library(dplyr)
library(htmltools)
library(lubridate)
library(tsibble)
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application
ui <- page_fixed(
    
        card(
            actionButton("submit", "Count rows")
        ),
        card(
            textOutput("start_finish")
        )
    
)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
    
    # Produce tsibble of event counts
    counts <- reactive({
        
        tibble(date_use = seq(ym("2023-01"), ym("2023-10"), by = "days")) |> 
            count(date_use, name = "events") |> 
            as_tsibble(index = date_use) |> 
            add_row(date_use = ymd("2023-10-02"), events = NA) |> 
            fill_gaps(events = 0)
        
    }) |> 
        bindEvent(input$submit)
    
    # Count rows
    output$start_finish <- renderText({
        
        nrow(counts())
        
    }) |> 
        bindEvent(input$submit)
    
}

# Run the application ----------------------------------------------------------
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

This is my first attempt to use shinylive, and I'm not good with Javascript so have limited abilities to debug its error messages. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
